# Quiero conectar una base de datos que tengo en Oracle con una que esta en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-12c

tengo un pequeño problema, lo que pasa es que tengo una base de datos en Oracle que tiene varias tablas una tabla de esas se llama publicación y tengo otra base de datos que esta en SQL Server donde también tengo varias tablas y una tabla que se llama persona, lo que pasa es lo siguiente:
La tabla persona que esta dentro de la base de datos de SQL Server esta relacionada con la tabla publicación que esta en la base de datos Oracle. Lo que quiero hacer es conectar Oracle con SQL Server para que pueda relacionarlas. Ya intenté hacerlo, pero no sé bien cómo hacerlo, he visto que para solucionar el problema tengo que modificar el archivo tnsnames.ora y pues lo que hice fue lo siguiente:

```
SQL =
 (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1433))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = MSSQLSERVER)
    )
  )
```

Y en Oracle hice el siguiente código:

```
create database link OrganozacionInvitado
    connect to admin identified by root
    using 'jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\MSSQLSERVER:1433;database=Organizacion';
```

Pero al momento de ejecutar una consulta de la otra tabla me aparece el siguiente error:

```
[66000][12154] ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the specified connection identifier
```

¿Qué tengo que realizar para poder hacer esa conexión entre base de datos y así poder realizar las fk de las tablas, algún video que tenga que ver o algo así?

Comment: ¿Modificaste listener.ora?

Comment: No lo he modificado, pero ¿Cómo tendría que modificarlo?

Comment: Vei que en su motor de base de datos Oracle crea un servidor vinculado. Tambien veo que colo a el codigo y mensaje de error del que le arroja una ejecucion en la base de datos Oracle, pero no coloca el codigo de la consiulta que intenta ejecutar. Creo wue debetia colocar el codigo y tb asegurarse que donde corre el servidor de oracles es la.misma maquina fisica (o virtual) donde se eiecuta la bd de sql server (ya que intenta accesarla con localhost). El tnsnames sobra, porque ceo que toda la informacion de la connection string a sql server esta literal en la definicion del servidor vinculado

Answer (score 0):

A ver si esto te sirve:

https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/crear-database-link-de-oracle-12cr2-a-sql-server-2017-1221

https://docs.oracle.com/es/learn/oci-adbs-db-link/index.html#task-12-create-database-link-from-an-autonomous-database-instance-without-wallet

Un saludo.

Fernan

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/407610)